# My jest test of a data access object is returning a user even after I clear out the database. what gives?

Tags: jestjs, sequelize.js

Clearly there is something wrong with my understanding of Sequelize, because *the way I think this should work* isn't actually how it works.

I have a jest test:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    await app.connectDB();
});

afterAll(async () => {
    await app.closeDB();
});

describe("account DAO tests", () => {
    test.only("what happens if i find all", async () => {
        const a = await activeAcctDAO.findAllAccounts();
        console.log(a, "22rm");
        expect(a.length).toBe(0);  // but I actually get length = 1
    });
});
```

Here is what happens in `app.connectDB()`:

```
public async connectDB() {
        if (this.dbConnOpen) return;
        App.initDB();
        await App.Database.authenticate();
        console.log("Database Connection Established");
        await initModels(App.Database);
        await App.Database.sync({ force: true });
        console.log("Database Sync"); 
           // this is console logged, hence shouldnt the db be empty because of .sync() ?
        this.dbConnOpen = true;
    }

    public async closeDB() {
        if (this.dbConnOpen) {
            await App.Database.close();
            this.dbConnOpen = false;
            console.log("db connection closed!");
        }
    }

    private static initDB() {
        // intialize testing database
        App.Database = new Sequelize({
            dialect: "postgres",
            host: TEST_DB_HOST,
            port: TEST_DB_PORT,
            database: TEST_DB_NAME,
            username: TEST_DB_USER,
            password: TEST_DB_PASSWORD,
            logging: false,
        });
    }
```

I expect that beforeAll will run the code to: (1) connect to the db (in "initDB") and then (2) App.Database.sync({ force: true }); resets the db tables to *completely empty*, hence (3) when my test runs, I should see 0 entries in the db.

I run this test with `npm run test:d`       defined in package.json as  `"test:d": "jest -i tests/dao/*",` so only the code in the `describe` func provided should run.

Please leave a comment helping me do a sanity check. What am I missing here?

Edit: I can confirm that my database connection is working. I know because I can run a test to add an account to the db, then run the test to `findAllAccounts` and receive an increased integer. Hence the db connection is active.

edit: two runs in a row

```
npm run test:d

> apgym@1.0.0 test:d
> jest -i tests/dao/*

  console.log
    hello world! 8000

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:117:9)

  console.log
    Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result

      at Sequelize.log (node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1271:15)

  console.log
    Database Connection Established

      at App.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:63:17)

  console.log
    Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result

      at Sequelize.log (node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1271:15)

  console.log
    Database Sync

      at App.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:68:17)

  console.log
    Dropping all tables...

      at App.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:74:17)

  console.log
    Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result

      at Sequelize.log (node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1271:15)

  console.log
    Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "passwordHash", "isVerified", "verificationToken", "verified", "updated", "role", "passwordReset", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt", "ReportId" FROM "Accounts" AS "Account" WHERE ("Account"."deletedAt" IS NULL);

      at Sequelize.log (node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1271:15)

  console.log
    db connection closed!

      at App.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:93:21)

 FAIL  tests/dao/account.dao.test.ts
  account DAO tests
    ✕ what happens if i find all (52 ms)

  ● account DAO tests › what happens if i find all

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 0
    Received: 3

      26 |         const a = await activeAcctDAO.findAllAccounts();
      27 |         // console.log(a, "22rm");
    > 28 |         expect(a.length).toBe(0);
         |                          ^
      29 |     });
      30 |     // test("try get acct i dont expect", async () => {
      31 |     //     const retrieved: Account[] = await activeAcctDAO.getAccountByEmail(FAKE_ACCOUNT.email);

      at tests/dao/account.dao.test.ts:28:26
      at fulfilled (tests/dao/account.dao.test.ts:5:58)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.073 s
Ran all test suites matching /tests\/dao\/account.dao.test.ts/i.
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
rlm@kingdom:~/Code/apGymBE$ npm run test:d

> apgym@1.0.0 test:d
> jest -i tests/dao/*

  console.log
    hello world! 8000

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:117:9)

  console.log
    Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result

      at Sequelize.log (node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1271:15)

  console.log
    Database Connection Established

      at App.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:63:17)

  console.log
    Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result

      at Sequelize.log (node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1271:15)

  console.log
    Database Sync

      at App.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:68:17)

  console.log
    Dropping all tables...

      at App.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:74:17)

  console.log
    Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result

      at Sequelize.log (node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1271:15)

  console.log
    Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "passwordHash", "isVerified", "verificationToken", "verified", "updated", "role", "passwordReset", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt", "ReportId" FROM "Accounts" AS "Account" WHERE ("Account"."deletedAt" IS NULL);

      at Sequelize.log (node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1271:15)

  console.log
    db connection closed!

      at App.<anonymous> (tests/mocks/server.ts:93:21)

 FAIL  tests/dao/account.dao.test.ts
  account DAO tests
    ✕ what happens if i find all (56 ms)

  ● account DAO tests › what happens if i find all

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 0
    Received: 3

      26 |         const a = await activeAcctDAO.findAllAccounts();
      27 |         // console.log(a, "22rm");
    > 28 |         expect(a.length).toBe(0);
         |                          ^
      29 |     });
      30 |     // test("try get acct i dont expect", async () => {
      31 |     //     const retrieved: Account[] = await activeAcctDAO.getAccountByEmail(FAKE_ACCOUNT.email);

      at tests/dao/account.dao.test.ts:28:26
      at fulfilled (tests/dao/account.dao.test.ts:5:58)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.803 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites matching /tests\/dao\/account.dao.test.ts/i.
```

EDIT2: I was able to go around the problem by writing `await Account.destroy({ where: {} });` in my `beforeAll`

edit3: here is `initModels`

```
function initModels(sequelize: Sequelize) {
    const Account = _Account.initModel(sequelize);
    const RefreshToken = _RefreshToken.initModel(sequelize);
    const ResetToken = _ResetToken.initModel(sequelize);
    const Report = _Report.initModel(sequelize);
    const Housing = _Housing.initModel(sequelize);
    const Gym = _Gym.initModel(sequelize);

    Account.hasMany(RefreshToken, {
        as: "refresh_token_owner",
        foreignKey: "refresh_token_owner_id",
    });
    RefreshToken.belongsTo(Account, { as: "refresh_token", foreignKey: "refresh_token_id" });

    Account.hasMany(ResetToken, {
        as: "reset_token_owner",
        foreignKey: "reset_token_owner_id",
    });
    ResetToken.belongsTo(Account, { as: "reset_token", foreignKey: "reset_token_id" });

    Account.hasMany(Report);
    Report.hasOne(Account);

    // todo: make city model. city has many gyms, has many apartments

    return { Account, RefreshToken, ResetToken, Report, Housing, Gym };
}

export default initModels;
```

My impression is that this attaches knowledge of the models to Sequelize. Perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: Please show `closeDB` and also console output for two runs in a row

Comment: I edited the OP to contain both @Anatoly

Comment: Seems like you missed to add `initModels` content